# SQL DESC on two coulmns in Oracle 10g express edition user HR

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Excuse me can anyone tell me how these two queries works?

1- `SELECT last_name,department_id,salary FROM employees ORDER BY department_id,salary`

2- `SELECT last_name,department_id,salary FROM employees ORDER BY department_id,salary DESC`

I'm trying to execute them on Oracle 10g Express Edition in user HR, the second one assumed to order the data according to the '**department_id**' but it isn't  !

Comment: What do you mean "how do they work"?. The second should first order by `department_id` on an ascending order and then by `salary` on a descending order

Comment: Dear @Lamak thanks for your quick reply I assumed the second one should work on a descending order for both department_id then salary.

Comment: For that, you need `ORDER BY department_id DESC,salary DESC`, the default order (if not specified) is `ASC`